# Issue with blank rows when merging files in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I recently started work and from time to time we're given the task to extract data from many excel files, however, they are kind enough to always format the data the same way, from A5:I5 and down, the files have varying amounts of rows containing the data

It's a macro that opens every Excel-file in a folder, grabs the data from A5:I5 and down, and pastes it into a separate document.

The problem is that some of the files that I want to merge are formatted in different ways, and my code can't deal with them properly. Some files only have one row at the bottom, which causes the need for the `TEXTbtm` and the removal of empty rows part

However, some files have empty lines in the data and the way the code is structured currently I miss out on all data below the first empty row.

/ProcessFiles:

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
Dim Filename, Pathname As String
Dim wb As Workbook

'Sets the folder containing files
Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Lists\"
Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xls")

'This part loops through all excelfiles in Lists and executes DoWork
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
    DoWork wb


    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Filename = Dir()
Loop

'After importing the data, this clears up any empty rows, from 1-5000
'This part is quite slow, but it works
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\NAME\Folder\Main.xlsx"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Range("A1:I5000").Select
Dim iCounter As Long
With Application
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
.ScreenUpdating = False
For iCounter = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(iCounter)) = 0 Then
Selection.Rows(iCounter).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next iCounter
.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With



'This part removes the rows with only TEXTbtm written in the first cell
'This happens as some files have only one row, and the xlDown in DoWork 
'then grabs blank rows at the bottom, including these.
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A1:I1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$3").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="TEXTbtm"
Range("A1:I1").Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Range("A1:A1").Select

End Sub
```

/DoWork:

```
Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook)
With wb

'selects A5:I5 and marks the underlying rows as well
 Range("A5:I5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

'Pastes the data into a file called Main, and selects the first empty row
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\NAME\Makro\Main.xlsx"
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

'clears what is copied, and closes the file
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close True



End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select` you can use the following:

```
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Cells.Find("*", Range("A1"), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
```

> lRow = the number of the last row

```
Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(lRow, 9)).Select
```

Edited: bracket missing